# Gmail custom themes: how to add a background image?

Tags: gmail

A little time-wasting activity of mine currently, is customizing my gmail theme. But, as I look around, I cannot find the option for adding a background image. Some themes have it, so I guess, it is possible.

Where is it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't - if you are going to create your own custom themes.

Background pictures are currently only supported for themes that are either 1) by Google themselves, or 2) by authorized artists' themes submitted to Google.

If you are really dying to tweak the LooknFeel of GMail, you might want to give [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com) + [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748) a shot.

Comment: Hmm. I thought as much (but was still hoping I missed something). Well, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Are there any themes by authorized artists? The themes Google made are a bit bland (while some are incredibly ugly).

Comment: @alex - I think he means those few themes that have the background image. If there are some themes apart from those in Gmail's interface, I'd love to hear about them.

Answer (score 1):

here's another FF addon "to tweak the LooknFeel of GMail":

**[Google Redesigned](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8434/)** - A complete redesign of popular Google services, Google Redesigned loads and manages several CSS stylesheets that change the appearance of popular tools.

[image]
<sub>(source: [jason-saggers.com](http://www.jason-saggers.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/google-redesigned.jpg))</sub>

and some more **['unofficial' Gmail themes](http://mashable.com/2008/11/21/custom-gmail-theme-scripts/)**